# xcode: label not showing after adding constraint

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a collectionViewCell, I added to it one label, I set constraint spacing to nearest neighbor to (0,0,0,0), so the must take all cell and adjust to its height and width, but the label is not showing at all.

I realized that what ever I put in a collectionCell, if I added to it a constraint, It well not be showing, so I ended up deleting all constraints and manually set label's height and width

CollectionViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var text:String?
    var delegate: TableViewCell?

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        loadFromNib() // load xib 

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapFunc))
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func tapFunc(_ sender: Any) {

        // head will not be clickable cuz parent here gonna be nil

        if let p = delegate {
            if p.isUserInteractionEnabledWith(cell: self){
                p.didTapeLabel(for: self, value: label.text!)
            }
        } else {
            print("parent at collectionview cell is nil")
        }
    }

    func fillOutData(_ text:String)  {
        label.text = text
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3Dtg.jpg)

I am building a multicolumn tableView :
tableView --> tableViewCell --> CollectionView --> CollectionViewCell --> label

Comment: Show some code may be?

Comment: Can you re-add the picture? And post your codes in your collectionViewCell.

Comment: You register collectionViewCell in any place ?

Comment: in the delegate

Answer (score 0):

Set data source and delegate for UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
   //collection View Delegates
   self.collectionView.delegate = self
   self.collectionView.dataSource = self
   super.awakeFromNib()            
}
```

Comment: already did that, and I said the label is showing only if I dont add constraints to it